# Powershell - excluding folders from string

Tags: powershell

I have a huge directory (several thousand folders), like so:

```
...\94000\abc\def\hig
...\95000\abc\def\hig 
...\96000\abc\def\hig
...\97000\abc\def\hig
...
```

So there is one part of the path that alternates but the rest of the folder structure is the same. Also lots of subfolders under abc and def, etc.

What I need to do is copy a specific file from let's say the folder "hig".

I am quite new to Powershell but managed to put together the following:

```
$destination = "C:\Users\etc..."
   $source = "B:\94000"
   Get-ChildItem $source -Filter "LIVE*.docx" -File -Recurse | Foreach {
          Copy-Item $_.FullName $destination
   }
```

I know it is very basic but it actually works. The problem is that it is quite slow, give the number of folders to sift through.

Is there any way to expedite things? I was thinking to make the script skip folders that I know do not contain the file I need.

I was also wondering if I could use a wildcard in the path so I could define the exact folders, like so:
\9*000abc\def\hig

But couldn't make either work.

Any idea is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can most definitely use wildcards like you implied. You can do:

```
Get-ChildItem B:\9*000\abc\def\hig\live*.docx
```

That should return files such as:

B:\94000\abc\def\hig\livesite.docx
B:\94000\abc\def\hig\live.docx
B:\95000\abc\def\hig\livefreeordie.docx
B:\96000\abc\def\hig\liverandonions.docx
B:\96000\abc\def\hig\livesinmomsbasement.docx

Then you can just pipe those to `Copy-Item -Destination $destination` like:

```
Get-ChildItem B:\9*000\abc\def\hig\live*.docx | Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Get-ChildItem` you can use `-Exclude` with a string to skip folders/files using. This may speed things up. Also, if you're using Powershell 2.0 `Get-ChildItem` is very slow. Upgrading to Powershell 3.0 or higher will make it much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards in the Path are supported by default.  As well, your filter is the fastest way to parse through the files (versus something like `Where-Object`).  Your `ForEach-Object` call may actually be slowing things down.  Another answer is correct in speeding things up in that respect since it can take pipeline input without adding another iteration step.

```
$destination = 'C:\Users\etc\'
$source = 'B:\94*00'
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter "LIVE*.docx" -File -Recurse |
  Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```